# While using SMTP in views.py file it is showing CSRF token error.I have enalbled EMAIL_USE_TLS as true

Tags: django, smtp

When the user is authenticated i want to use smtp server to send the mail,But it is showing CSRF token error

Comment: A CSRF error has *nothing at all* to do with sending email, but is caused by failing to include the token in your POST. See [the CSRF docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Cross Site Request Forgery prevention security-token is missing. Django checks for it in html requests.
You'll need to ensure this template-tag is included in your html templates, often needed wherever you have an html form.

`{% csrf_token %}`

For example:

`<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}`